# usage of any and every

Tags: grammar

"Any' or 'every': Which one should I use in the following sentences?

1- I am against everyone/anyone who hates people based on their skin colour and religion.

2- He loves me more than anyone else/everyone else does.

Comment: 2 can be just "He loves me more than anyone else".

Comment: 1-  *everyone*... 2- *anyone*